# If I stumble into an enemy outpost and then leave, can I come back later for the undetected bonus?

Tags: far-cry-3

I accidentally stumbled into an enemy outpost while gliding.  They spotted me and summoned reinforcements. I bailed and they lost track of me.

**If I go back later to clear that outpost for a Path Of The Hunter mission, will I be able to get the undetected bonus, or do the guards always remember that they detected me once they've seen me?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tried this out for you and **yes, you can go back and get the undetected bonus.**

Comment: Yes, I've done this a couple times. However, interestingly if you alarm them so much that they call in reinforcements, then each time you come into range of the output, you'll see the "Reinforcements" popup at the top of the screen. I tried leaving, doing a mission, and waiting literally days before returning and it kept coming back. If you let the reinforcement timer go all the way down, then leave, then come back, then you can still achieve the "undetected" experience.